# How to make React Calendar Range NOT select the current date when it first renders

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

I'm using React Calendar https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar and I want to select a range of days with clicking from a Start Date and End Date. I used the selectRange prop in Calendar, but the first time the Calendar renders, without even clicking anything, the range selector will automatically have the begin date as today's date. I do not want this. I want to load the calendar with a clean state and then when I start clicking that will be the begin date, then i can click the next element for the end date. How can I accomplish this?

Here's my code:

```
export default function TestCalendar() {
    const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date())

    return(
        <>
        <Calendar selectRange={true} onChange={onChange}
        value={value} minDate={new Date()} minDetail={"year"} navigationAriaLabel={"Go up"} activeStartDate={null}/>

        {value[0] != null && <><div>{value[0].toString()}</div><div>{value[1].toString()}</div></>}

        </>
    )
}
```

This is the functionality example that I Don't Want (when it loads it will automatically select today's Date (June 5th) then I start hovering to click for the End Date):
https://i.gyazo.com/91ec726a453c2b138f9c1b0aae09e1a6.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured out the answer. I was copying the starter code and I didn't know that the value prop also set the Beginning value. If I remove that prop from <Calendar />, then everything works fine and I can just select the beginning date without it automatically getting the current date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialized `value` to today (`new Date()`) and assigned to `Calendar`'s `value` prop. I suggest you to use `defaultValue` (to use react-calendar in an uncontrolled way).